# List<string> name to string

Tags: c#

How to get the `List<string>` name to string.
For example:

```
private static void Print(List<string> listString)
{
    Console.Write("The List<string> name is ");
    // ???
}
```

And result:

```
The List<string> name is listString.
```

Comment: `nameof()` in C# 6.0? Or just *hardcode* `"The List<string> name is listString"`

Comment: Can i ask why you need to know the name of the variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C#-6, you can use the [`nameof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx):

```
Console.Write($"The List<string> name is {nameof(listOfString)}");
```

Although I should note that this will print "listOfString" each time, unless you actually change the parameter name. This will not print out the name of the variable that was passed as an argument to the method call.